# Artificially intelligent commuter spacecraft story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence

I am searching for the title of a story that I read forty-odd years ago; I had thought that the story was in "Time and Stars" by Poul Anderson, but I was mistaken. The story concerns a passenger commuter spacecraft controlled by an onboard AI. The ship is on an empty run, having discharged its passengers, when it discovers a baby on board. The ship notifies its controller, who tells it that the baby is just a misplaced cybernetic doll. The ship believes that the baby is alive, and dying, and it breaks out of its programmed course to take the infant to help. Upon arrival, the infant proves to be a real baby.

Comment: Sounds similar to "the ship that sang" series by Anne McCaffrey none of them that I remember had that setting but it might help jog the memory some. If it fits the writing style also was the book old like from the golden age of science fiction that could help narrow it down also
 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ship_Who_Sang

Comment: Definitely not "The Ship Who Sang". I read the story in question in 1976, I believe. I paid no attention to the copyright date then, but the book was already old. Perhaps it was an Isaac Asimov story; the commuter ship seemed bound by the three laws of robotics, disobeying an order to remain on its course because it felt required to save the baby.

Comment: Regarding my previous comment: I've scanned an Asimov short story bibliography without finding this very short tale.

Comment: Was it a collection of short stories or only just the one though we narrow the year range already